# (net)SNMP can GET but not SET

Tags: router, snmp, openwrt, net-snmp, mib

I am running OpenWRT (tried all 3 latest versions) in a TP-LINK WDR3600, with snmpd and snmp utils installed. I can get (although MIBs seem missing) but not set OIDs.

SNMPGET

```
root@OpenWrt:/# snmpget -v 1 -c public 10.0.0.2 iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TUNNEL-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-FLOW-LABEL-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = STRING: "HeartOfGold"
```

SNMPSET

```
root@OpenWrt:/# snmpset -v 1 -c private 10.0.0.2 iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 s test
MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TUNNEL-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-FLOW-LABEL-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Error in packet.
Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
Failed object: iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
```

CONFIGURATION

```
root@OpenWrt:/# cat /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
agentaddress UDP:161
sysLocation office
sysContact bofh@example.com
sysName HeartOfGold
com2sec ro default public
com2sec rw localhost private
group public v1 ro
group public v2c ro
group public usm ro
group private v1 rw
group private v2c rw
group private usm rw
view all included .1
access public "" any noauth exact all none none
access private "" any noauth exact all all all
exec  filedescriptors /bin/cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
```

Any hints? 
Thank you

Comment: Update: By including -m ALL in the flags I get rid of the "Cannot find module.." errors. But still cannot write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OIDs set in the config file become read-only so this is why iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 is writable only if sysName is not set in config.
To have meaningful MIBs, able to write to them and produce effect, one must load them or extend the agent himself.